# NoSuchMethod when trying to create a SPARQL query with jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, arq

I am trying to make some SPARQL queries using vc-db-1.rdf and q1.rq from ARQ examples. Here is my java code:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.* ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.*;
import java.io.*;
public class querier extends Object 
{
static final String inputFileName = "vc-db-1.rdf";
public static void main (String args[]) 
{
    // Create an empty in-memory model 
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    // use the FileManager to open the bloggers RDF graph from the filesystem
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    if (in == null) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }
    // read the RDF/XML file
    model.read( in, ""); 
    // Create a new query
    String queryString = "PREFIX vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> SELECT ?y ?givenName WHERE { ?y vcard:Family \"Smith\" . ?y vcard:Given  ?givenName . }";
    QueryFactory.create(queryString);
}
}
```

Compilation passes just fine.
The problem is that the query is not even executed, but I am getting an error during creating it at line

```
QueryFactory.create(queryString);
```

with the following explanation:

```
C:\Wallet\projects\java\ARQ_queries>java querier
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRI.
resolve(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRI;
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.n3.IRIResolver.resolveGlobal(IRIResolver.java:191)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.createIRI(SystemInfo.java:31)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.<init>(SystemInfo.java:23)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.init(ARQ.java:373)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.<clinit>(ARQ.java:385)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query.<clinit>(Query.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:68)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:28)
    at querier.main(querier.java:24)
```

How can i solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the IRI library on the classpath (the IRI library is separate from the main Jena JAR). Jena has runtime dependencies on several other libraries which are included in the `lib` directory of the Jena distribution. All of these need to be on your classpath at runtime (but not necessarily at compile time).

Comment: Damn, i've checked it once again (after already 3 times) and found that i've made a mistake writing "iri.jar" in classpath (was written as "jri.jar"). thank you!

Comment: Assuming Java 6 or higher, wildcards in the classpath are supported, so you could just say something like "-cp lib/*"